# How to keep tor browser bundle updated

Tags: apt, 14.04, tor

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I decided to install the tor browser bundle today. After some quick research online i discovered [this article](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) specifically discouraging users from using the Ubuntu packages as they aren't updated. The repo they operate for tor doesn't include the tor browser. So i had to download it manually. I am able to run the tor browser but i'm not able to create a shortcut to it on the launcher or figure out how to ensure i have the latest version. (E.g. apt-get update/upgrade)

So my question is this: Since the tor browser is a manual download, and not from a package repo, how do i ensure it stays up to date? Will the bundle check online each time its run? Or is it up to me now to check the Tor site often to ensure i have the latest version. I'm just curious how others are dealing with this issue.

Comment: See http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/318/how-do-i-keep-my-tor-browser-bundle-current

Comment: I remember that the default page opened by Tor Bundle ("Are you using Tor?" like page) shows an warning if your bundle version is too old, so it kinda checks for a new version every time you run it. It didn't tell you any minor (non-security important) updates, however.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Tor browser PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/tor-browser-bundle-ubuntu-ppa.html) that webupd8 maintains, of course you don't get any warranty using a third party repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```